# Expression does not receive a value. Unsure of the right razor code using html.renderpartial() in vb.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am studying mvc asp.net and following the tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866143/Learn-MVC-step-by-step-in-days-Day

This is in C# and I'm coding in vb.net.

I am unable to find the solution online. I am stuck.

```
@For Each employee As MvcApplication1.EmployeeViewModel In Model.Employees
      @<tr>
      <td>@employee.EmployeeName</td>
      <td style="background-color:@employee.SalaryColor">@employee.Salary</td>   
      </tr>

   Next employee

   </table>

</div>
@*tried using this*@

 @Html.RenderPartial("Footer", Model.FooterData)

 @*tried using this as well*@

@Code
    @Html.RenderPartial("Footer", Model.FooterData)
End Code
```

This is the code in my EmployeeListViewModel

```
Public Class EmployeeListViewModel
    Public Property Employees As List(Of EmployeeViewModel)
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property FooterData As FooterViewModel
End Class
```

The EmployeeController Index Action Method

Function Index() As ActionResult

```
        Dim elvm As EmployeeListViewModel = New EmployeeListViewModel()
        Dim empBL As EmployeeBusinessLayer = New EmployeeBusinessLayer
        Dim employees As List(Of Employee) = empBL.GetEmployees()
        Dim evms As List(Of EmployeeViewModel) = New List(Of EmployeeViewModel)
        elvm.UserName = User.Identity.Name
        elvm.FooterData = New FooterViewModel
        elvm.FooterData.CompanyName = "Sample Company"
        elvm.FooterData.Year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()
        For Each emp As Employee In employees
            Dim evm As EmployeeViewModel = New EmployeeViewModel
            evm.EmployeeName = emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName
            evm.Salary = String.Format("{0:C}", emp.Salary)
            If emp.Salary > 300 Then
                evm.SalaryColor = "pink"
            Else
                evm.SalaryColor = "green"
            End If
            evms.Add(evm)
        Next (emp)
        elvm.Employees = evms
        Return View("Index", elvm)

    End Function
```

FooterViewModel

```
Public Class FooterViewModel
    Public Property CompanyName() As String
    Public Property Year() As String
End Class
```

Footer.vbhtml

```
@modeltype MvcApplication1.FooterViewModel
<div style="text-align:right;background-color: silver;color:Navy;border: 1px solid gray;margin-top:2px;padding-right:10px;">
@Model.CompanyName &copy; @Model.Year
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("_Comments");}
```

You can directly give your view name

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 @Code
   Html.RenderPartial("Footer", Model.FooterData)
 End Code
```

not

```
  @Code
   @Html.RenderPartial("Footer", Model.FooterData)
  End Code
```